# Partitioner for JdbcCursorItemReader - Reader must be open before it can be read

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I had a working spring batch job which when I tried to make multi-threaded using a partitioner I started getting Reader must be open before it can be read.

```
org.springframework.batch.item.ReaderNotOpenException: Reader must be open before it can be read.
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doRead(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:443) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:88) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:157) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:116) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:110) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:139) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:136) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]

2016-08-01 14:26:14.700 ERROR 12716 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step partitionStep in job exportMasterListCsv

org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Partition handler returned an unsuccessful step
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.PartitionStep.doExecute(PartitionStep.java:112) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:392) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(JobLauncherTestUtils.java:152) [spring-batch-test-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at com.myer.pricing.onlinestore.export.job.ExportMasterListCsvTest.testLaunchJob(ExportMasterListCsvTest.java:60) [test-classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
```

I was just wondering if JdbcCursorItemReader  is not threadsafe hence maybe why I am getting this error?

Here is roughly how I have set my job up...

```
@Configuration
public class ExportMasterListCsvJobConfig {

public static final String JOB_NAME = "exportMasterListCsv";

@Autowired
public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
  return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
}


/**
 * Create job to export the master list from the online pricing staging db.
 * 
 * @param readStgDbAndExportMasterListStep read online staging db step and export to csv
 * @return job to export the master list from the online pricing staging db.
 */
@Bean
public Job exportMasterListCsvJob(@Qualifier("partitionStep") Step partitionStep) {

    return jobBuilderFactory.get(JOB_NAME)
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(partitionStep)
            .build();
}

  @Bean
  public Step partitionStep(@Qualifier("readStgDbAndExportMasterListStep") Step readStgDbAndExportMasterListStep){
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("partitionStep")
        .partitioner(readStgDbAndExportMasterListStep)
        .partitioner("readStgDbAndExportMasterListStep", partitioner())
        .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
        .build();
  }

/**
 * Read from online pricing staging db.
 * 
 * @param chunkSize
 * @param queryOnlineStagingDbReaderForMasterList
 * @param masterListOutputProcessor
 * @param masterListFileWriter
 * @return step to read from online pricing staging db.
 */
@Bean
public Step readStgDbAndExportMasterListStep(
        @Value("${exportMasterListCsv.generateMasterListRows.chunkSize}") int chunkSize,
        @Qualifier("queryOnlineStagingDbReaderForMasterList") ItemReader<MasterList> queryOnlineStagingDbReaderForMasterList,
        @Qualifier("masterListOutputProcessor") ItemProcessor<MasterList,MasterList> masterListOutputProcessor,
        @Qualifier("masterListFileWriter") ItemWriter<MasterList> masterListFileWriter) {

    return  stepBuilderFactory.get("readStgDbAndExportMasterListStep")
                .<MasterList,MasterList>chunk(chunkSize)
                .reader(queryOnlineStagingDbReaderForMasterList)
                .processor(masterListOutputProcessor)
                .writer(masterListFileWriter)
                .build();

}   

/**
 * Query and map rows from online pricing staging db into a master list object.
 * 
 * @param onlineStagingDb
 * @param masterListSql
 * @return
 */
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemReader<MasterList> queryOnlineStagingDbReaderForMasterList(
        DataSource onlineStagingDb,
        @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[divisionId]}") Integer divisionId,
        @Value("${exportMasterListCsv.generateMasterListRows.masterListSql}") String masterListSql) {

    JdbcCursorItemReader<MasterList> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();

    reader.setDataSource(onlineStagingDb);
    reader.setSql(masterListSql);   
    reader.setPreparedStatementSetter(new PreparedStatementSetter() {
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            ps.setInt(1, divisionId);
        }
    });


    reader.setRowMapper(new RowMapper<MasterList>() { 
        @Override 
        public MasterList mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
            MasterList masterList = new MasterList();
            masterList.setL1(resultSet.getString(DaoConstants.COLUMN_HEADER_LEVEL_ONE));

            return masterList;
        } 
    });         
    return reader;
}   

@Bean
public Partitioner partitioner(){
    return new DivisionPartitioner();
}
```

I've been doing some reading on the net. Is this possibly related to https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1301 ?
thanks

Comment: Only part of the code was pasted in correctly; the `queryOnlineStagingDbReaderForMasterList` is cut off.

Comment: added some more of my implementation for you to have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was just wondering if JdbcCursorItemReader is not threadsafe hence
>   maybe why I am getting this error?

The JdbcCursorItemReader is an AbstractCursorItemReader which in turn is an AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.

According to the documentation implementations of the AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader are **not** threadsafe

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.html

> Abstract superclass for ItemReaders that supports restart by storing
>   item count in the ExecutionContext (therefore requires item ordering
>   to be preserved between runs). **Subclasses are inherently not
>   thread-safe.**

This part of the log hints towards a threading issue:

```
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
```

Try running it sequential by setting the taskexecutor to use only one thread.

```
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(1);
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

Comment: Hi, setting the concurrencyLimit to 1 still gives me the same error. But thank you for pointing out that the stack trace shows that this has something to do with threading. Still looking for a solution to this problem if anyone has any ideas. thanks

Comment: I've been playing around with bean scope for this code and I think it has got me somewhere. I have a different question now about how to scope my beans. I think I'll close this question off and start a new one specific to the scope question. thanks for your help

Comment: Glad that it helped you. With regards to bean scope, it has to do with the binding of properties (as in, at what moment in time), see http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#step-scope

Answer (score 1):

This happens due the returning type of the reader

```
public ItemReader<MasterList> queryOnlineStagingDbReaderForMasterList
```

It should be **changed** to `JdbcCursorItemReader` which is the reader being built at that method.

```
JdbcCursorItemReader<MasterList> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
```

Otherwise the visibility of the methods for the bean reader gets limited to a higher level and its not able to open the reader correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When reading for the first time, it takes a long time for the reader to be ready. Sometimes rowMapper can get too ahead and it thinks that reader is not open, when it's simply still in the process of opening. To solve this problem, just put rowMapper to sleep the first time you are using it. Add the following block to your setRowMapper and see if the error goes away.

```
try {
    if(firstTime) {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        firstTime = false;
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```