# Spring Batch - Chunking & Multithreaded steps - Nullpointer exception in RowMapper

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-batch

When I run my step in multiple threads, I am getting a null pointer exception inside my row mapper while processing the result set even for entries which have an explicit null check. Works fine when i execute it without the `taskExecutor()`/on single thread. I am confused about few things. My understanding is, if I specify the commit interval as 100 and the core thread count as 10, each thread pulls a chunk of 100 each and works on it independent.

- How does chunking- reader-row mapper trio work? If I have a query inside my reader fetching 1 million rows and chunk size of 1000, does this mean the reader will hit database 1000 times? And after each time the row mapper will be mapping all the 1000 rows fetched?  **How does threading effect row mapper?**

Code as below:

```
@Bean
public Step myStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get(STEP_NAME).<MyModel, MyModel> chunk(1000)
            .reader(myModelReader())
            .writer(myModelWriter())
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .listener(stepExecutionNotificationListener)
            .listener(chunkExecutionListener)
            .build();

}

@Bean
public Job myJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get(JOB_NAME)
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(jobCompletionNotificationListener)
            .flow(myStep()).end().build();

}

@Bean
@StepScope
public JdbcCursorItemReader<MyModel> myModelReader(){
    JdbcCursorItemReader<MyModel> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    reader.setVerifyCursorPosition(false);
    reader.setSql("my query fetching millions of records joining multiple tables from the db");
    reader.setRowMapper(new MyModelRowMapper());

    return reader;
}

public class MyModelRowMapperimplements RowMapper<MyModel>{

    @Override
    public MyModel mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
      MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
      myModel.setEmailAddress(checkIsEmpty(rs.getString("EMAIL_ADDRESS")) ? "" : rs.getString("EMAIL_ADDRESS").replace("|", "")); // ----- The line which is failing!!! -----
      return person;             
    }

}
public boolean checkIsEmpty(String stringToCheck)
{
    if(stringToCheck==null || stringToCheck.isEmpty() || stringToCheck.equals("null"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor=new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(25);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(5);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyModelBatch-");
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
    return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
}
```

**Edit 1**

Apart from working in non-threaded context, it also works if i use resultset once.
I changed my code as

```
String email = rs.getString("EMAIL_ADDRESS");
myModel.setEmailAddress(checkIsEmpty(email) ? "" : email.replace("|", ""));
```

Comment: Are you asking how Spring Batching works or how to fix an NPE?

Comment: I was hoping to fix the NPE by understanding how it works. Fair?

Comment: No, because you assumed that the NPE is somehow related to threading. Either run a debugger and see what's null, or decompose the error line to multiple lines so you can see the exact line where the NPE happens. Your `RowMapper` is threadsafe, so you should start by checking the simple things before you blame threading for your problems (and batching was built for multithreading from the ground up).

Comment: As for your chunks and db hits, you're correct. 1000 chunk size makes 1000 db hits for 1 million rows.

Comment: 1. I have already tried that before posting the question. rs.getString("EMAIL_ADDRESS").replace("|", "") fails regardless of the null checks i provide. And the value of the expression keeps changing when i try to evaluate it in debug between null and a valid value. 2. Regarding 1000 db calls. Is that a good practice in general to have that many db hits?

Comment: It's possible (although a bit unlikely) that `rs.getString()` would return `null` after the first call (although it's more likely you've made a typo in the column name), so keep on debugging. It's a NPE after all, not something that's difficult to solve. Your `checkIsEmpty` method is flawed with the  `stringToCheck=="null"`. Come on, you should know that Strings are compared with `equals()`.

Comment: Yes. I was just about to edit with this. I tried moving results to a variable and things looks fine till now. Any idea why this comes up only when threaded Or why does it come at all? And regarding null check, I corrected it, was trying few things and lost mind somewhere!

Comment: Sorry, I've given you some false information. The chunk size affects only the single transaction size. With the given `JdbcCursorItemReader`, the DB call keeps the cursor open in the database, so you're actually hitting the database (for reading) only once. In any case it shouldn't be possible for the `ResultSet` to change inside `mapRow`, since there are no multiple threads involved when the mapping is done. But Spring Batch is a weird creature, I had problems with it myself a few years ago.

Comment: Well I did a write-up below based on all the info you've given. Maybe you'll get some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JdbcCursorItemReader` is not thread safe (See its [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcCursorItemReader.html) and more details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38696807/5019386)). The reason for this is that the it wraps a single `ResultSet` which is not thread safe.

So your issue is due to using a non-thread safe item reader in a multi-threaded step. According to the Javadoc:

> Each call to `read()` will call the provided RowMapper, passing in the ResultSet.

Since `read` is not synchronized, each thread can call it to read items.

To fix your issue, you can wrap your Jdbc reader in a `SynchronizedItemStreamReader`.

Comment: It does work. But, In that case, changing to JdbcPagingItemReader should do the job right? Won't the wrapping with SynchronizedItemStreamReader slow down my step

Comment: yes that's possible, but most importantly it makes your program correct. Changing to JdbcPagingItemReader is a good option. `It does work.`: in this case, please accept the answer.

Comment: JdbcPagingItemReader should be the right answer right? And i have seen people online people wrapping it even in SynchronizedItemStreamReader. What are we trying to achieve doing so by wrapping a thread safe reader inside a synchronized item stream.

Comment: No need to wrap the JdbcPagingItemReader in a synchronized decorator since it is already thread-safe (See its [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.html))

Answer (score 0):

Since processing a `ResultSet` is a sequential operation, and it's being done by your `RowMapper` inside the `JdbcCursorItemReader`, there shouldn't be any possibility of thread interference (the code is pretty simple if you look at it: `read row` -> `map row to obj` -> `return obj`).

`ResultSet` shouldn't return different values for repeated calls to `getXXX` either, although that's probably not guaranteed (although it would be a bizarre implementation, and I've never heard of a driver that would do that).

So for you to be able to get the described bug, the `ResultSet` would have to be shared between two `JdbcCursorItemReaders`, but I really can't see how that could happen, threads or no threads. Then you might be able to get a situation where the resultset has been advanced already, but again...they can't share `ResultSets`.

This could be some configuration issue, but I haven't done Spring Batch in a while, so can't say off the top of my head.